# Get a list of Outlook rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've set a few rules in outlook. And I'd like to get a list of all the rules I've created so far. How do I get this  ?

Thanks

Comment: which version of outlook are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Outlook version, this might have a slightly different label/location, but in the latest Outlook versions you should have an item called `Rules and Alerts` in the `Tools` menu, where you can see the rules created so far (this should be the same place as where you initially created the rules as well).